# how to set the parameter NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS in the project instead of the scripts

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, httprequest

I have an api testing project build with node.js and Jest which send http requests to multiple domain using the 'request-promise' npm package.
lately I started to use an api with a new domain and received the following error:

> RequestError: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

from my research I found that I needed to set the parameter 'NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS' with the path to my .pem file with the certificates.
this solution works only if I'm setting the parameter in the cli scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./src/bin/HarelCerts.pem&&set NODE_ENV=test&&node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -i"
  }
```

in my *package.json* file
but when i set it in my *.env* file it stops working, I printed the parameter to the console to verify that it was added to my process.env, and it was, so I don't know what is the problem.

Since I don't like the script implementation, is there another, better way to do it?